# How to manage class library evolution in Visual Studio 2013/TFS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget

We have developing a class library to help our development process. This library consists in a solution with 3 different projects/assemblies:

```
CustomLibrarySolution
|
|--CustomLibrary.Mvc
|--CustomLibrary.Persistence
|--CustomLibrary.Persistence.NHibernate
```

Every project has NuGet dependencies that, at the time of the initial CustomLibrary development, has package versions updated to the last, looking something like this (a few libraries, for simplicity):

```
CustomLibrarySolution
|
|--CustomLibrary.Mvc [NuGet: log4net 1.2]
|--CustomLibrary.Persistence
|--CustomLibrary.Persistence.NHibernate [NuGet: NHibernate 3.0]
```

So, we make our first project using this library, and the solution looks like this:

```
MyFirstProject
|--Libs
   |--CustomLibrary.Mvc.dll [NuGet: log4net 1.2]
   |--CustomLibrary.Persistence.dll
   |--CustomLibrary.Persistence.NHibernate.dll [NuGet: NHibernate 3.0]
|--MyFirstProject.Web [CustomLibrary.Mvc.dll AND NuGet: log4net 1.2]
|--MyFirstProject.Core [CustomLibrary.Persistence.dll]
|--MyFirstProject.Core.NHibernate [CustomLibrary.Persistence.NHibernate.dll 
                                   AND NuGet: NHibernate 3.0]
```

And everything worked fine.

Now, in our 2nd project, the issue that why I'm writting this, appears:

```
My2ndProject
|--Libs
   |--CustomLibrary.Mvc.dll [NuGet: log4net 1.2]
   |--CustomLibrary.Persistence.dll
   |--CustomLibrary.Persistence.NHibernate.dll [NuGet: NHibernate 3.0]
|--My2ndProject.Web [CustomLibrary.Mvc.dll AND NuGet: log4net 1.3] <-- newer version
|--My2ndProject.Core [CustomLibrary.Persistence.dll]
|--My2ndProject.Core.NHibernate [CustomLibrary.Persistence.NHibernate.dll 
                                 AND NuGet: NHibernate 4.0] <-- newer version
```

The project builds OK, and runs fine; BUT I suspects that this is not OK based on:

- The `packages` folder for `My2ndProject` contains the 2 version folders

> ```
> NHibernate 3.0
> NHibernate 4.0
> log4net 1.2
> log4net 1.3
> ```

- When I inspect one of this `My2ndProject` assemblies with a tool like **Reflector.NET**, it shows TWO dependencies (NHibernate 3.0 and NHibernate 4.0). For example, that cause me a headache trying to install a windows service with InstallUtil because it throws an AssemblyLoadException searching for NHibernate 3.0.

I was thinking about this situation, and one of the posible solutions that I have arrived to, is to copy the Class Library projects every time I use them in a new project, instead of copying just the dlls. This will allow updating the class library NuGet dependencies, to the exact same versions that are references in the new project.
The problem with this approach is that we will lost the TFS versioning for Class Library. Instead, the library will exist in N repositories.

Is there something that I can do to improve this approach?

Comment: Why are you not using a single set of dependencies? This kind of mess usually gets out of control very, very quickly.

Comment: You mean that in 2ndProject, use NHibernate 3.0 instead of NHibernate 4.0 right?

Comment: Whichever is more desirable. I'd assume that using the newer version is better so I'd upgrade the library. Loading multiple versions of a dependency into the same process is not a good idea.

Comment: At the end of the day, you really only want one version of every external library to be loaded into the process to avoid various version mismatch issues. It's much simpler to deal with a single set of dependencies.

Comment: Ok, but that's the problem. If I upgrade the class library, then I will have to upgrade the dependencies of 1st project, if I want to deliver the classlibrary bug fix or improvement to it.

Comment: you can just create a new version of the class library with updated dependencies. The old version will still use the old dependencies - whoever has that library, will use those older dependencies. For your project, fork a new version of the class library, update dependencies and use those.

Comment: I'm afraid that this one will be the way to go. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project 2 has a direct dependency on NHibernate 4.0 and a "transitive" dependency on NHibernate 3.0 (via the library).  At least that's the terminology I use when talking to people about this problem.

I wrote a blog post about this problem, and strategies to solve it here: http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/01/27/151951.aspx

The gist of it is you need to have a versioning policy in place for your various components, and you use assembly binding redirects to solve the problem of not being able to load multiple versions into the same process.

Luckily, NuGet basically does all the hard work for you (figuring out an acceptable version based on policies, and creating binding redirects), you just have to specify the versioning policies in the various nuspec files.

Here's the nuget docs on how to specify versioning policies: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning

And here's a great blog post on how to have NuGet generate the binding redirects for you: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/nuget-versioning-part-3-unification-via.html

Comment: That kind of NuGet version configuration is what I was looking for. Thank you very much